# Problems with redirection while implementing oAuth2 for blackberry using webworks

Tags: oauth, soundcloud

I am trying to implement a SoundCloud app for blackberry phones using webworks frame work.

I am using OAuth2 scheme for authorization. So far I am able to display the SoundCloud log-in page from where the user can allow the app. But the problem occurs during the redirect which is essentially done by SoundCloud. The redirect page which is being pointed to by the call back URI is residing in my device, but after the user approves the app I get a page saying "something went wrong".  However when I try to bounce the redirect from a third server, it just works fine. In this case I specify the callback URL pointing to a page on a website which only forwards the request to the page which is residing on my device. But the problem is that I do not want to use this "bounce server"

Could you please look into the code and advise if I am doing something wrong.

```
/**
 * Authenticates the app against soundcloud
 * This javascript method is called in the index.htm of my application.
 */
authenticate : function(){
    var url = "https://soundcloud.com/connect?" + "scope=nonexpiring&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&" +
              "response_type=code&redirect_uri=local:///testpage.htm";
    window.location = url;
;

/************************************/
```

`testpage.htm` only displays "hello sound cloud".

Any help in this regard shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but having the `local:///` protocol might be part of it. I don't know much about webworks, but could you try using a localhost address and see how that goes?

Comment: nickF ----- I have tried with localhost as well but that does not work. The reason why i am writing local:/// is that in blackberry the resources for webworks app are by default stored at this location so my reidrect page shall be placed at "local:///myfile.htm" in my phone.

Answer (score 1):

The value for the `redirect_uri` parameter must match the value of the "Redirect URI" on the app edit page.

Example: https://img.skitch.com/20120411-q6yqada29tcadnep15jc6q75a1.jpg

IHTH
Hannes

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the triple slash part in your redirect_uri. Although, it is a valid URI according to the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3), the Ruby URI library behaves a bit strange when parsing such values. We're working on a fix.

In the meantime, could you try to use local:/testpage.htm?

Comment: By the way i found another problem that you guys might want to look into. If there is an underscore sign in the redirect url that is specified on the app settings on soundcloud website , that url is not saved instead an empty field is stored.